# How to copy std::queue<char> into std::string?

Tags: c++, reference, char, queue, std

I am struggling with this piece of code :

```
std::queue<char> output_queue;
std::string output_string
// put stuff into output_queue
while (!output_queue.empty())
    {
    output_string.insert(0,(output_queue.front()));
    output_queue.pop();
    }
```

I somehow can't do this since `std::queue<char>::front()` will return a `char&` and I can't put this into `std::string`.

Comment: You may want to use a deque if you want to use the iterator interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing an argument to make `insert` insert a character. You need to specify how many of that character:

```
output_string.insert(0, 1, output_queue.front());
```

If you want to make it easier on yourself, you can also use `std::deque` instead of `std::queue` and replace it with this:

```
std::deque<char> output_queue;
//fill output_queue in same way, but use push/pop_front/back instead of push/pop

std::string output_string(output_queue.begin(), output_queue.end());
output_queue.clear();
```

It would nearly be the same thing as now because your `queue` is actually using a `std::deque` by default under the hood. The `deque`, however, supports iterators, which makes this possible without ugly code that relies on the underlying storage.

Comment: *"However, your whole code could be replaced with this"* - No, it can't. `std::queue` is a container adaptor without any iterator functionality.

Comment: @ChristianRau, Holy cow, I'm learning a lot today. I figured it would, being a standard container. I'll have to fix that. Does it at least have contiguous storage?

Comment: No, they don't. A [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) doesn't meet any container requirement. Don't confuse it with a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (which might be used by the `std::queue` internally, but is inaccessible, anyway). As long as he doesn't use an actual container (like a `std::deque` directly), the first part of your answer is still the best solution in his case.

Comment: @ChristianRau, I just found it. There's an optional underlying container argument for `std::queue` that defaults to `std::deque`, which does not have contiguous storage. I guess you could specify `std::vector` as the underlying container if you wished for this solution.

Comment: This won't buy you anything, since you don't have access to the underlying container afterwards, anyway. Or is it `string(&output_queue.front(), &output_queue.front()+output_queue.size())` that you want to use? Meh, should even be defined behaviour when using a `std::vector` internally, but still doesn't *look* that nice.

Comment: The best solution in the end would be to just use a `std::deque` isntead of a `std::queue` and then use its iterator interface just like you described.

Comment: @ChristianRau, I agree. It's more trouble than it's worth trying to do it idiomatically with `std::queue`.

Comment: @chris Not sure if it is thread-safe, say if several other threads are still push more characters into this queue, so how do you deal with that then?

Comment: @haohello, I don't remember anything from almost 5 years ago, but use a concurrent queue. There's no standard one, but there isn't a shortage of third-party libraries that include one.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
output_string += (output_queue.front());
```

and then (after while) `reverse` it